# When using abs() it shows "abs is ambiguous" but when I try it on another editor it works

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In my code abs() isnt working but when put in a different code editor it does work. I dont know what to do. Cant find answers anywhere. Please help. Error: ("abs" is ambiguousC/C++(266))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x = -1;
    int a = abs(x);

    cout<< a;

}
```

Comment: Is taht a message from your compiler or IDE?

Comment: Removing the `using` and writing `std::abs` might remove that IDE warning.

Comment: Probably related, if not the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378761/error-with-abs-in-c

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: The error is not related to abs() itself, but it is a code quality issue detected by the C/C++ extension by Microsoft for the Visual Studio Code editor. (please add this note to the question when S.O. will allow edition again later - it's currently overflowed...)

Answer (score 1):

More information will be helpful. There's no need to add "using namespace std" here. You can try to modify "int a = abs(x);" ==> "int a = ::abs(x);"

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>`, as written in the question, is required to put all the names into `std`, and it is **allowed** to put the names into the global namespace. So `::abs` isn’t required to work. `std::abs` will see all the names. To use `::abs`, the appropriate header is `#include <stdlib.h>`, which puts all the names into the global namespace and is **allowed** to put the names into `std`.

Comment: I did above test on Visual Studio 2019(C++17 ), and it works fine.  Actually, cstdlib has already included the stdlib.h

Comment: Yes, that’s the point: it **might** work; it is not **required** to work. Not even in a future version of a compiler for which it now works.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x = -1;
    int a = fabs(x);

    cout<< a;

}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    int x = -1;
    int a = abs(x);

    std::cout << a;

}
```

Comment: For completeness and fewer surprises, the examples should include <cmath>.

Answer (score 0):

As commented earlier under the question, the error is not related to abs() itself: it's a code quality issue detected by the C/C++ extension by Microsoft for the Visual Studio Code editor which is somewhat inappropriate.

*Workaround:*

> [The] error description go away if I either a) make the namespace
> explicit at the site of the supposed error (not that this is always
> desirable) or b) edit the definition and declaration to make them
> temporarily invalid and then edit them back (not that this leaves me
> confident that the squiggle won't come back).

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/showing-error-is-ambiguous-even-though-the-code-co/405607